# putty : export or import tunnel settings to another computer

Tags: putty

I have a set of tunnels in my putty. how do i export my tunnel settings?The tunnel images are as below.

[image]

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It would belong to [su]. But it's answered there dozen times already. Please google before you ask. For example [How can I export my Putty configuration?](https://superuser.com/q/118441/213663).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PuTTY settings are shared in HKEY_CURRENT_USER in the registry, so you can export these to a file for use elsewhere. To export, run RegEdit.exe and navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY. Right click on the PuTTY entry in the tree and select Export. Save this file to your thumb drive or H: drive.

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions. Vote them to be closed instead.

Comment: They may be off-topic but the answer was VERY helpful and saved me a lot of time! Voting to NOT close this!